# failed for URL: "snapchat://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme snapchat"

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to use SnapKit, specifically Login Kit, and when I try to send the user to Snapchat to log in, I get the message in the debugger :

```
 -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "snapchat://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme snapchat".
```

I also get in the debugger:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <SFSafariViewController: 0x7fb65485e800> on <App.LoginViewController: 0x7fb653f1f5f0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

This is the code I have to try and log in:

```
import UIKit
import SCSDKLoginKit

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {
 @IBOutlet weak var loginButton: UIButton!
 @IBOutlet weak var messageLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func Loginn(_ sender: Any) {
        SCSDKLoginClient.login(from: LoginViewController()) { (success: Bool, error: Error?) in
                if success {
                    // Needs to be on the main thread to control the UI.
                    self.displayForLoginState()
                }
                if let error = error {
                    // Needs to be on the main thread to control the UI.

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.messageLabel?.text = String.init(format: "Login failed. Details: %@", error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                }
            }
        // loginButtonDidTap()
    }
}

extension LoginViewController {
        fileprivate func displayForLogoutState() {
            // Needs to be on the main thread to control the UI.
            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                self.logoutButton?.isEnabled = false
                //self.loginView.isHidden = false
                //self.profileView.isHidden = true
                self.messageLabel?.text = LoginViewController.DefaultMessage

            }
        }

        fileprivate func displayForLoginState() {
            // Needs to be on the main thread to control the UI.
            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                self.logoutButton?.isEnabled = true
                //self.loginView?.isHidden = true
              //  self.profileView?.isHidden = false
                self.messageLabel?.text = LoginViewController.DefaultMessage


            }

            displayProfile()
        }

        fileprivate func displayProfile() {
            let successBlock = { (response: [AnyHashable: Any]?) in
                guard let response = response as? [String: Any],
                    let data = response["data"] as? [String: Any],
                    let me = data["me"] as? [String: Any],
                    let displayName = me["displayName"] as? String,
                    let bitmoji = me["bitmoji"] as? [String: Any],
                    let avatar = bitmoji["avatar"] as? String else {
                        return
                }

                // Needs to be on the main thread to control the UI.
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.loadAndDisplayAvatar(url: URL(string: avatar))
                    self.nameLabel?.text = displayName
                }
            }

            let failureBlock = { (error: Error?, success: Bool) in
                if let error = error {
                    print(String.init(format: "Failed to fetch user data. Details: %@", error.localizedDescription))
                }
            }

            let queryString = "{me{externalId, displayName, bitmoji{avatar}}}"
            SCSDKLoginClient.fetchUserData(withQuery: queryString,
                                           variables: nil,
                                           success: successBlock,
                                           failure: failureBlock)
        }
```

Not sure what the next steps are. If you have any ideas, please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the schemes you try to open in your app in the `info.plist` file. Add these lines in your `info.plist` right after the first `<dict>` keyword you see when you open it as source code.

```
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>snapchat</string>
    </array>
```